# Prove that $T^2$ is the zero transformation if and only if $\mathrm{range}(T) \subseteq \ker(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\range}{\mathrm{range}}$The full question:

$T^2$ means the composition, i.e. $T(T(x))$

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be linear.  Prove that $T^2$ is the zero transformation if and only if $\range(T) \subseteq \ker(T)$.

So far I know that for ($\implies$).  Assume $T^2$ is the zero transformation.  Then $\ker(T^2)=\{0 \in V: T^2(v)=0\}$.  Note that this is $\forall v \in V$. We also know that the $\range(T)=\{0\in V: \exists v \in V: T^2(v)=0\}$.

Not sure where to go from here.  Also for the other way, I don't know where to go.

Comment: What you've written for $\ker(T^2)$ and $\mathrm{range}(T)$ is a bit strange, and for the range, it's not correct. The definitions are $\ker(T^2)=\{v\in V:T^2(v)=0\}$ and $\mathrm{range}(T)=\{T(v):v\in V\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\operatorname{ran}(T)\subseteq\ker(T)$. Then for any $x\in V$, $$T^2(x)=T\big(T(x)\big)\in T[\operatorname{ran}(T)]\subseteq T[\ker(T)]=\{0\}\;,$$ so $T^2(x)=0$.

Conversely, suppose that $T^2$ is the zero transformation, and let $x\in\operatorname{ran}(T)$. Then $x=T(y)$ for some $y\in V$, and $T(x)=T^2(y)=0$, so ... ?

Answer (score 2):

This is very straightforward.

Suppose $T^2$ is the zero map.  Then for any $v \in V$, $T^2(v) = T(T(v)) = 0$, which implies that $T(v) \in \ker T$ for any $v$.  Hence $\{T(v): v \in V\} = T(V) \subset \ker T$.  Now suppose, $T(V) \subset \ker T$.  For any $v \in V$, $T^2(v) = T(T(v)) = 0$, so $T^2$ is the zero map.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\range}{\mathrm{range}}$**Hint:** Assume by negation that $\range(T)\not\subset\ker(T)$ and take
$v\in \range(T)$ s.t $v\not\in \ker(T)$.

What can you say about $T(v)$
? can you find a vector $u$ s.t $T^{2}(u)\neq0$ ?

The other direction should be straightforward using the definitions (of composition, $\ker(T)$ etc')