# Range space equal to null space for a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \rightarrow V $ be a linear transformation and $R(T),N(T)$ denote range space and null space for $T$ respectively. $O$ is the zero operator.? The dimension of V is finite and even(to satisfy rank nullity theorem).  Is it possible to show $T^2=O \implies R(T) = N(T)$.

I could show $R(T) \subset N(T)$. Whether other inclusion namely $N(T) \subset R(T)$ is possible for such $T$ in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $T^2 = 0$. Then:

- $R(T) \subseteq N(T)$ (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203170/prove-that-t2-is-the-zero-transformation-if-and-only-if-ranget-subseteq) for a proof.)
- It is possible for $R(T) = N(T)$. For example, consider $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, (x, y) \mapsto (y, 0)$.
- It is not necessarily true that $N(T) \subseteq R(T)$: Consider the zero transformation on any non-zero vector space.

Answer (score 0):

$O^2=O$, but $N(O)\not\subseteq R(O)$, unless $V=0$.